# WebSecurityConfig at the Springboot version 3

Tags: spring-boot, websecurity

I'm having a problem with Spring Boot version 3 code, in which the WebSecurityConfig class is in the previous version and with the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extension. I want to change it to the current version of Spring Boot, but I'm having problems. How do I update? Here's the line of code:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
@CrossOrigin
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users", "/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().cors();          
}
}
```

I already tried this code, but the post didn't work:

```
  @Configuration @EnableWebSecurity public class WebSecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
              .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                      .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login")).permitAll()
                      .anyRequest().authenticated())
              .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration bean should be something like;

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class WebSecurityConfig{

   @Bean
   protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     return httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .cors(withDefaults()).build()
   }
  }
```